# Why does yup throw 'cyclic dependency' at all?

Tags: javascript, yup

I don't get why yup throws cyclic dependency at all.
When referring to other fields, we are referring to value, not the schema itself aren't we ?

More than just something that I don't get, I found myself blocked while requiring a conditional schema validation.

```
const yup = require("yup");

it("should pass", async () => {
  const schema = yup.object({
    name: yup.string().when("name", {
      is: name => name !== "dummy",
      otherwise: yup.string().email("Email or dummy.")
    })
  });

  const obj = {
    name: "dummy"
  };

  await expect(schema.isValid(obj)).resolves.toBe(true);
});
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-poitras-p6ts2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Also, is there nothing like `or` or `either` into the DSL ?

The question is really about, why does yup throw cyclic dependency, **not about this specific case.**

Comment: I have not used yup, but a quick look at the documentation and it looks like a yup schema should be defined with `yup.object().shape({/*object properties here*/})`

Comment: Ok, I completely failed my codesandbox link. It's actually the one from the documentation so both work. Code sandbox updated.

Answer (score 1):

Getting around the problem with:

```
const schema = yup.object({
    name: yup.string().when([], (v, { originalValue }) => 
      originalValue.name === "dummy" ? yup.string() : yup.email("Email or dummy")
    )
);
```

But it doesn't look like the natural way, + I still don't get how a schema can generate cyclic dependency.